# How to dynamically bind images from store to carousel in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, carousel

I have the following Store declared in my sencha touch application

```
Ext.define('Sample.store.ImageStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: 'Sencha.model.ImageModel',
        data: [{ name: "cat", url: "http://bleachthemind.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/cute-bunnys-domestic-animals-2785589-1024-768.jpg" },

            { name: "lion", url: "http://images1.fanpop.com/images/photos/2600000/Cheetah-Family-wild-animals-2603080-1280-1024.jpg" }
        ]
    }
});
```

This is my code being declared in Model:

```
Ext.define('Sample.model.ImageModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {

     fields:['name','url']
}
});
```

I am facing difficulty to construct a view  with carousel where data is being binded from the store mentioned above.Please can i know the right syntax to be written in the view with the carousel consuming store data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot hook up Store into Carousel in Sencha Touch. It seems that you have to manually do it through some way like this:

```
yourCarousel = Ext.getCmp('your_carousel_id');
store.each(function(record){
                    yourCarousel.add({
                        html: '<img src=' + record.get('url') + '/>'
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,the code mentioned above by you should  be placed in the store right?

Comment: Yes, or in any controller functions because you can easily get your store through `Ext.getStore('your_store_id')` as well

Comment: My view which consumes the store looks like this 
Ext.define('Sample.view.ProductsView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'productsview',
    config: {

        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Products'
        }],
        items: [{
            xtype: 'carousel',
            store: 'ImageStore',
            
           
        }]
});

Comment: if you set `id:'imageCarousel'` to your carousel declaration, so `Ext.getStore('ImageStore')` equals to `store` and `Ext.getCmp('imageCarousel')` equals to `yourCarousel` in my above code snippet. Then you can write that code wherever you want

Comment: I changed my view syntax to this ,its not workingExt.define('Sample.view.ProductsView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'gallery',
    id:'imagecarousel',
    config: { dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Products'
        }],
      items: [{
            xtype: 'carousel',
            store: 'ImageStore',
            id:'imagecarousel',
            initComponent:store.each(function(record){
                    imagecarousel.add({
                        html: '<img src=' + record.get('url') + '/>'
                    });
                });
  }]


});

Comment: `initComponent` is deprecated in Sencha Touch 2. Do not use it, you'd better place this in your store's `load` function

Comment: Thanks for the reply , as you mentioned i have made changes to store's load function ,but images are not loading load:function() {
             var imagecarousel = Ext.getCmp('imagecarousel');
             store.each(function (record) {
                  imagecarousel.add({
                      html: '<img src=' + record.get('url') + '/>'
                  });
              });
          }

Comment: ok, last thing to try, explicitly place them in your app.js `launch` function

Answer (score 3):

Thiem's answer is fine.
If you want a more complete example, have a look at this nice post:
http://edspencer.net/2012/02/building-a-data-driven-image-carousel-with-sencha-touch-2.html

I think it should cover all your needs ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i tried to follow the same example, but the problem is their is too much of code in app.js file , which is not ideal, i want my app.js file to be minimal

Comment: borck's reply is a good suggestion if you want to build something like an extension which you'll use many times programmatically. By the way, the core is they use `push` or `add` to add images to carousel manually, so as long as you know this trick, it's up to you to choose the suitable way.